# How to initialize flex List with XML data

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, web-applications

My application is Adobe Flex 4 based

I have an XML as follows :

```
<data>
   <GENERAL _index="0" DESCRIPTION="DEAD TIME" CODE="D" _count="1"/>
   <REQUEST>
      <PARAMETERS>
         <page>db/ocr_valid_opr_category.xsl,db/sql.xsl</page>
         <maj_cd>COC</maj_cd>
      </PARAMETERS>
   </REQUEST>
</data>
```

I want to initialize my List (Adobe Flex 4) with data in GENERAL tab which you see is "Description" and "Code" values , this is dynamic XML and changing continiously , how can I set the data in GENERAL tab as my data provider for List in Flex 4 . I want Description as LabelFeild of the list and codeCode as the back end value for list , I hope you understand ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,

We need to change that XML structure for List dataProvider should be XMLList so only we can show list of items so we need to add XML Element in between.

You can access the CODE attributes like `list.selectedItem.@CODE.toString()`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">   `<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var xml:XML = <data>
                                <list>
                                   <GENERAL _index="0" DESCRIPTION="DEAD TIME" CODE="D" _count="1"/>
                                   <REQUEST>
                                      <PARAMETERS>
                                         <page>db/ocr_valid_opr_category.xsl,db/sql.xsl</page>
                                         <maj_cd>COC</maj_cd>
                                      </PARAMETERS>
                                   </REQUEST>
                                </list>
                                <list>
                                   <GENERAL _index="1" DESCRIPTION="ENOUGH TIME" CODE="E" _count="2"/>
                                   <REQUEST>
                                      <PARAMETERS>
                                         <page>db/ocr_valid_opr_category.xsl,db/sql.xsl</page>
                                         <maj_cd>COC</maj_cd>
                                      </PARAMETERS>
                                   </REQUEST>
                                </list>
                              </data>;  

        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(list.selectedItem.@CODE.toString());
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:List id="list" labelField="@DESCRIPTION" dataProvider="{new XMLListCollection(XMLList(xml.list.GENERAL))}"
        change="list_changeHandler(event)"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a top level xml node to include your xml data:

```
    private var xml:XML =
            <xml>
            <data>
              <GENERAL _index="0" DESCRIPTION="DEAD TIME" CODE="D" _count="1"/>
              <REQUEST>
                <PARAMETERS>
                <page>db/ocr_valid_opr_category.xsl,db/sql.xsl</page>
                <maj_cd>COC</maj_cd>
              </PARAMETERS>
             </REQUEST>
           </data>
           </xml>;

      [Bindable]
      private var dataList:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xmlOne.data);
      ...
      private function labelFunc(item:Object):String {
        return item.GENERAL.@DESCRIPTION;
      }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:VGroup>
    <s:List dataProvider="{dataList}" labelFunction="labelFunc"/>
  </s:VGroup>
```

to refrence the "CODE" is just like "DESCRIPTION":item.GENERAL.@CODE.